# Does Azure Data Explorer take care of ingestion's transient failures automatically in queued ingestion?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm using `IKustoIngestClient.IngestFromStorageAsync()`. I see some `transient` failure type when querying `.show ingestion failures`. Does Azure Data Explorer recover from these automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, up to a predefined amount/time of retries.

For monitoring "final" statuses of queued ingestions, you should probably use the API described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/netfx/kusto-ingest-client-status and demonstrated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/netfx/kusto-ingest-queued-ingest-sample#code